# In Node/Express, how to fetch the current route handler?

Tags: node.js, express

How do I fetch the syntax/name of the current route handler, ignoring the current specific param values?

e.g.:

```
app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    let route = ?
    console.log(route) // --> "/users/:id"
})
```

(Question 2 - can I do this in a middleware function?)

Comment: its in `req.route.path` and yes you can

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is `req.route.path`

e.g.

#### 1. Call directly from main file (app.js / index.js):

```
app.get('/admin/:foo/:bar/:baz', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(req.path);
    console.log(req.route.path);  // this one is your answer
    console.log(req.baseUrl);
    console.log(req.hostname);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

API call:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/a/b/c
```

Output

> `/admin/a/b/c`           (originalUrl)
> `/admin/a/b/c`           (url)
> `/admin/a/b/c`           (path)
> `/admin/:foo/:bar/:baz`  (route.path)
> `<nothing>`              (baseUrl)
> `localhost`              (hostname)

---

#### 2. Call from a module:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

...

const users = require('./users');
app.use('/api/users', users);
```

users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

...

router.get('/admin/:foo/:bar/:baz', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(req.path);
    console.log(req.route.path);  // this one is your answer
    console.log(req.baseUrl);
    console.log(req.hostname);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

API call:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users/admin/a/b/c
```

Output

> `/api/users/admin/a/b/c`           (originalUrl)
> `/admin/a/b/c`           (url)
> `/admin/a/b/c`           (path)
> `/admin/:foo/:bar/:baz`  (route.path)
> `/api/users`              (baseUrl)
> `localhost`              (hostname)

Answer (score 0):

You can see below example for information about `req` object that you get.

`/users` can be obtained from `req.baseUrl` and `:id` can be obtained from `req.params.id`

```
app.use('/admin', function (req, res, next) { // GET 'http://www.example.com/admin/new?a=b'
  console.dir(req.originalUrl) // '/admin/new?a=b' (WARNING: beware query string)
  console.dir(req.baseUrl) // '/admin'
  console.dir(req.path) // '/new'
  console.dir(req.baseUrl + req.path) // '/admin/new' (full path without query string)
  next()
})
```

Comment: OP wants `/users/:id`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i'm giving more detailed use case with all other possible options.

Comment: ok, but it doesn't include what the OP wants, i.e if its `'/admin/:foo/:bar/:baz'`, OP seems to want `/admin/:foo/:bar/:baz`, reread the question

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  `/users` can be obtained from `req.baseUrl` and `:id` can be obtained from `req.params.id`

Comment: @FerinPatel ! OP doesn't want the "value of" id, but wants the exact route i.e. `/users/:id` not `/users/john` or `/users/1`